# Redirect to Another Page within Object Page - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, redirect

I have 2 pages.

**page1.html**

```
<object width="100%" height="550px" data="URL"></object>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
<body>
Other Content

<object width="100%" height="550px" data="page1.html"></object>

Other Content

</body>
</html>
```

On mobile devices, ***page1 redirects to page3*** . Currently, when I load page2, it is completely redirected to page3 just because it is having a object / iframe redirecting to page3.

I need it to redirect within page2 like

page2 should be

```
Other Content

<object data="REDIRECTED TO PAGE3 BECAUSE OF MOBILE DEVICE"></object>

Other Content
```

Redirection should not be done on top level page. Looking for help. Thanks.